# Why can I not use SETB to set a bit in P1MDOUT?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, 8051

Why can I not use `SETB` to set a bit in `P1MDOUT`? Also, how would I show in assembly language how to set bits 0 and 6 of `P1MDOUT` (leaving the other 6 bits unchanged).

Comment: yes UART needs to 0

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I not use `SETB` to set a bit in *P1MDOUT*?

Considering:

- The `SETB` instruction is used to set one of the 256 directly accessible bits.
- The Special Function Register (SFR) *P1MDOUT* is located at address 0xA5.
- SFRs with addresses ending in 0x0 or 0x8 are bit-addressable as well as byte-addressable. All other SFRs are byte-addressable only.

We can conclude that the SFR ***P1MDOUT* is byte-addressable only** because its address ends in 0x5. Therefore we can't use the `SETB` instruction that is reserved for operating on the bit-addressable registers and the internal memory range from 20h to 2Fh.

> Also, how would I show in assembly language how to set bits 0 and 6 of P1MDOUT (leaving the other 6 bits unchanged).

```
ORL 0xA5, #0x41
```